# How to add or convert a gradient to color

Tags: android, gradient, drawable

I am using a library for my view. I need to set the activity's bar color to a gradient in java,

```
setBarColor(getDrawable(R.drawable.background_gradient));
```

however it's showing an error,

> setBarColor cannot be applied to android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.

How can I use my custom gradient?

Comment: Please add some more code. What does the `setBarColor` method require for input?

Comment: setBarColor requires an (int Color) input

Comment: Try using just `setBarColor(R.drawable.background_gradient);`

Comment: It does work, but it sets a different color. My gradient color has a dark orange tint as the starting color and light orange tint as the end color, but by that method it sets it to a uniform blue color

Comment: Can you show the `setBarColor` code?